# Gradle - Error:Failed to find: com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, okhttp

I just try to use [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) but I have the following issue when I sync my gradle file with Android Studio :

> Error:Failed to find: com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0

Here is the dependencies part of my build.gradle file :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
}
```

Comment: For newer version see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34895397/not-able-to-import-com-squareup-okhttp-okhttpclient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the following block to the build script:

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
```