# not able to import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;

Tags: android, gradle, okhttp

I am working on android studio and  fetching some data from the web. I tried using `OkHttpClient` and also added jars to my project folder but still i am unable to import it.

It shows `can't resolve symbol okhttp`.
I tried some solution but unable to solve the problem.Here is my **build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
 //   compile files('libs/okhttp-3.0.1.jar')
   // compile files('libs/okio-1.6.0.jar')


}
```

Comment: where is your libs folder? is it inside app folder or outside?

Comment: @RRR libs folder is inside app folder

Comment: @Rohit5k2 okhttp3 is also not resolved

Comment: @ManishSingla: Please see my answer about how to add it in the gradle file.

Comment: Stop hard binding in your project level build.gradle:

`ext {
    minSdkVersion = 14
    targetSdkVersion = 22
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'
    // dependencies versions
    supportLibraryVersion = '28.0.0'
    playServicesVersion = '16.0.0'
    versionCode = 12
    versionName = "1.74"
    butterknife = "8.8.1"}`. 'complile' keyword is obsolete. It is changed to 'implementation'

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Gradle should have a line like this

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
```

and this is how you import it

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
```

Because `OkHttpClient` has been moved from package `com.squareup.okhttp` to `okhttp3` in the last version.

More details are [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp) and [here](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/)

Comment: after adding compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1' to build.gradle build is successful but now it shows can't resolve symbol okhttp3

Comment: @ManishSingla: Sorry my bad. It was typo. Please see the new import statement.

Comment: compile keyword is obsolete now please use implementation

Answer (score 2):

I see you are/were trying to compile with a jar you manually put in your `libs` folder. Is there a reason for this (such as you need that specific version of the library etc.)? In case you didn't notice, the lines are commented out - that means they will not be processed and thus not added to your application.

Possible solutions:

1. Try adding this latest version to your `dependencies` instead:

   ```
     implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
   ```

Source: https://github.com/square/okhttp

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following libraries:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

use the latest version of it!

In my case, tried all the possibilities but after updating to the latest version, the issue is resolved.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Let gradle handle download and import for you:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ...
}

dependencies {
...
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'

}
```

And change your import from `com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient` **to**

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
```

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle import as api, e.g.

```
dependencies {
api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
```

see this note https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java#when-i-use-okhttp3requestor-in-dbxrequestconfig-i-get-errors-like-class-file-for-okhttp3okhttpclient-not-found