# Gradle can't resolve any of my dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.0

For some reason gradle can't resolve any of my dependencies. This is an example:

**Module:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.simplelogin"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Project:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When I try to sync or build, I get the following error:

```
Failed to resolve: com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1
```

I get this same error message with every dependency I try to add - anyone know why?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34895397/not-able-to-import-com-squareup-okhttp-okhttpclient

Comment: @aconnelly: No, it isn't. The accepted answer there is what wj1091 is already doing.

Comment: Could you post more of your Gradle Console output around the point of the message that you have listed? Also, is there anything unusual about your network (e.g., need to use a proxy server)?

Comment: You could try the latest version. https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

You probably have switched on offline mode in the Gradle tool window of Android Studio. Switch off offline mode and it should work if you have internet connection.