# Gradle error - could not download okhttp.jar file 2.7.2

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, okhttp

when i added the firebase functions library **(implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.0')** , android studio(3.1.4) throws "**Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download okhttp.jar (com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2)**"

I tried to add "**implementation files('libs/okhttp-2.7.2.jar')**"  but still got the same error.

**this is my build.gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'  

android {    
    compileSdkVersion 27  
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'  
    defaultConfig {  
        applicationId "com.caliber.mskhan.calibergaming"  
        minSdkVersion 16  
        targetSdkVersion 27  
        versionCode 1  
        versionName "1.0"  
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"  
    }  
    buildTypes {  
        release {  
            minifyEnabled false  
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'  
        }  
    }  
}    

dependencies {  
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')  
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'  
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'  
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'  
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'  
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'  
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'  
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'  
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'  
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'  
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'  
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'  
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'  
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'  
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'  
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'  
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'  
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'  
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'  
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'  
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'  
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.0'  
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'  
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.1'  
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'  
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'  

    //implementation files('libs/okhttp-2.7.2.jar')  
}  
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**this is my build.gradle(project)**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[build errors after gradle sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRM4y.jpg)

Comment: try  invalidate caches then rebuild the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Change this 


// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.0.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.0.4'
After adding the above dependency , i tried commenting other dependendencies and synced 
After the sync was done removed the comments and tried resync 
issue is resolved for me

Answer (score 0):

Ref: [not-able-to-import-com-squareup-okhttp-okhttpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34895397/not-able-to-import-com-squareup-okhttp-okhttpclient)

Gradle should have a line like this

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
```

and this is how you import it

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
```

Because OkHttpClient has been moved from package com.squareup.okhttp to okhttp3 in the last version.

More details are [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp) and [here](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/)

Answer (score 0):

change classpath

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

its working with me