# Gradle Could not download okhttp.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0)

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to add payments to my app with the use of [pesapal](https://github.com/lycin/pesapalandroid/blob/master/README.md) but having a problem, I added their dependency `implementation 'com.pesapal.android:pesapalandroid:1.0.5'` to my app and ever since I have been the

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download okhttp.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0)
```

I tried using google and was let to this question on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52014868/gradle-error-could-not-download-okhttp-jar-file-2-7-2)
but to no avail, I have found the library Maven [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.8.0) but I do not know how to add that maven path to my top level gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it like this

```
implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '3.8.0'
```

and to get dependencies from maven you need to add this to your repositories

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Do you know another way where I can add the path to the top level gradle?

Comment: @AubryLungu Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @AubryLungu Ok, however it's not needed here.

Comment: @AubryLungu https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#remote-repositories

Comment: @MuratKaragöz: sir  in which gradle put above line  porject level gradle or  app level gradle folder?