# ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download okhttp.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.3.1)

Tags: android, maven, gradle

After newing project, I met a error that I can not handle when I am tring to add a gradle in `app/build.gradle`

Please help me!

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.3.1") //that's the thing I want
}
```

ERROR

> CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 57s ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download okhttp.jar
>   (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.3.1) Show Details Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>   Could not download okio.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.1) Show
>   Details Affected Modules: app

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/55039363 help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55039363): you can add it like this

```
implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '3.8.0'
```

and to get dependencies from maven you need to add this to your repositories

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```