# Unity Android : unable to resolve class okhttp3.OkHttpClient

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I'm trying to deploy an App on Android.

**The problem**
I first got the following error : `can't resolve symbol okhttp` and now I keep getting `unable to resolve class okhttp3.OkHttpClient` because of the importing line.

**What I've tried**
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34895397/not-able-to-import-com-squareup-okhttp-okhttpclient) similar post I added a custom `Main Gradle Template`
[image]

and I added the two following lines :

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1' 
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
```

Here is the complete Gradle file :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
// Must be Android Gradle Plugin 3.6.0 or later. For a list of
// compatible Gradle versions refer to:
// https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
flatDir {
dirs 'libs'
}
}
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
**APPLY_PLUGINS**

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1' 
**DEPS**}
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

android {
    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
        noCompress = ['.ress', '.resource', '.obb'] + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')
    }**PACKAGING_OPTIONS**
}**REPOSITORIES****SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**
**EXTERNAL_SOURCES**
```

Comment: `import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;` why are you doing this in gradle file? Do you add this `implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1' ` dependencies in your subprojects?

Comment: Because from what I understood I had to add this in the Gradle file. Where should I put it @Vencat ?

Comment: This has to be there in your java or kotlin source file.